# Windows 10 time out of sync - Dualboot removed

Tags: windows, time, date

I have been struggling with my windows 10 time for months now. It has been out of sync since I installed a Duelbooted Ubuntu OS. I tried all the solutions recommended on here that I could find but nothing worked. I hadn't used the Ubuntu system in a while so I decided to remove it from my system, hoping this would solve the time issue. But, the issue remains. My clock is off by +6 hours. Everything I have tried has failed, hoping someone can help me figure this out.

What I have tried:

- Changing Ubuntu to use RTC time.
- Restarted/register/etc w32tm.
- Reset UEFI settings
- Remove Ubuntu, try all these again
- Windows basic Sync Now returns "Time Synchronization failed"

Comment: "My clock is off by +6 hours." - Your time is off by 6 hours because you enabled RTC.  It sounds like the services are not running.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you clarify what services should be running? I have tried to fix any services issue on my end a couple times now with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Some fixes for time problems:

1. Temporarily disable your firewall and security software
2. Set Windows Time service to automatic:

   - Run the Services applet
   - Find the "Windows Time" service and double-click it
   - Verify that "Startup type" is set to "Automatic"
   - Click Start, Apply, OK.
3. Use a different server

   - Right-click the taskbar clock and select "Adjust date/time"
   - Ensure that "Set the time automatically" is set to On
   - On the right click "Date, time & regional formatting"
   - Verify the data and click
     "Additional date, time & regional settings"
   - Click "Set the time and date"
   - Go to "Internet Time" tab and click "Change settings"
   - The setting of "time.windows.com" should work for you,
     or you could click the down-arrow to change it
     (or enter your own server).
   - If you changed the time server, click "Update now" and OK.
4. Re-register the Windows Time service:

   - Run Command Prompt as Administrator
   - Paste-in the following commands, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each:

     ```
     net stop w32time
     w32tm /unregister
     w32tm /register
     net start w32time
     w32tm /resync /nowait
     ```
   - Reboot.